# how to convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<AnonymousType#1>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<>'.

Tags: c#, linq

I need to convert the following linq to a List directly,if I convert it to list I still get the error I explained on the subject,its said I need to convert it to list,but still the error is there,how can I convert it to list of string?without using additional conversion like foreach,...

```
List<string>  eventResult= (from c in DB.Events
                        where (c.m_turbine_id == turbineid.turbineID) && (c.m_time_stamp >= frmDate && c.m_time_stamp <= toDate)

                 select new EventLogPartialViewModel
                 {
                     Timestamp = c.m_time_stamp,
                     Description = c.m_event_log_description,
                     WindSpeed = c.m_wind_speed,
                     RPM = c.m_rpm,
                     Power = c.m_power
                 }).ToList().Select(x => new
                           {
                               Timestamp = x.Timestamp.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy H:mm:ss"),
                               Description = x.Description,
                               WindSpeed = x.WindSpeed,
                               RPM = x.RPM,
                               Power = x.Power
                           }).ToList().OrderByDescending(m => m.Timestamp);
```

the first part of the above linq,i get the data and convert to list because I need to change my time stamp format,any help will be appreciated .

Comment: Why don't you project into concrete type?

Comment: How do you intend to represent an object with five properties in a `string`?

Comment: @JLRishe yes because I need to get a csv file out of it and for my conversion to byte I need list of string –

Comment: Ok, so your question should be about how to convert an arbitrary object to CSV. All the Linq stuff is pretty much a distraction.

Comment: @JLRishe yes but I need to get a list of string for that right?or im not in a right direction?

Comment: @moris1983 It sounds like you need a way to turn your anonymous objects into CSV lines (strings). Then if you produce a list of _those_, you will have a list of strings.

Comment: @JLRishe exactly

Comment: @moris1983 Ok, then you need your question to be about _that_ because at present, you haven't mentioned CSV in your question even once.

Comment: @JLRishe I created new question for that,but yet not answered ,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you need to create list of comma separated values with header,

```
//Add headers as first item
List<string>  eventResult = new List<string>(){"Timestamp,Description,WindSpeed,RPM,Power"};

//Add records
eventResult.AddRange(from c in DB.Events
                        where (c.m_turbine_id == turbineid.turbineID) && (c.m_time_stamp >= frmDate && c.m_time_stamp <= toDate)

                 select new EventLogPartialViewModel
                 {
                     Timestamp = c.m_time_stamp,
                     Description = c.m_event_log_description,
                     WindSpeed = c.m_wind_speed,
                     RPM = c.m_rpm,
                     Power = c.m_power
                 }).ToList().Select(x => 
                      x.Timestamp.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy H:mm:ss")) + "," +
                      x.Description + "," +
                      x.WindSpeed + "," +
                      x.RPM + "," +
                      x.Power

                 .ToList());
```

Comment: no I need all of them,this just gives me time stamp

Comment: do you need comma separated values?

Comment: yes because I need to get a csv file out of it and for my conversion to byte I need list of string

Comment: check updated answer, it will return comma separated values

Comment: its nice,but I haven't the name of headers here,i only have the values with your solution,for example:description,timestamp...are not there,i also need them in case of export to csv

Answer (score 1):

In the Linq query, you are selecting anonymous complex type so you can't assign it a `List<string>`. You should use `var` to keep reference of anonymous type.

```
var eventResult= (from c in DB.Events
                        where (c.m_turbine_id == turbineid.turbineID) && (c.m_time_stamp >= frmDate && c.m_time_stamp <= toDate)

                 select new EventLogPartialViewModel
                 {
                     Timestamp = c.m_time_stamp,
                     Description = c.m_event_log_description,
                     WindSpeed = c.m_wind_speed,
                     RPM = c.m_rpm,
                     Power = c.m_power
                 }).ToList().Select(x => new
                           {
                               Timestamp = x.Timestamp.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy H:mm:ss"),
                               Description = x.Description,
                               WindSpeed = x.WindSpeed,
                               RPM = x.RPM,
                               Power = x.Power
                           }).OrderByDescending(m => m.Timestamp).ToList();
```

Also, the ideal way is creating a class for complex type to handle reference instead of using  anonymous type.

Comment: I used var,but in need list of string,because I want to convert them all to byte and then download as csv file,thats my point

Comment: I suggest you to convert to .csv file after retrieving the records as complex type class.